# Create a pie chart

Tags: code-golf, graphical-output

The challenge is simple:

**Create a pie-chart based on a number of input values.**

The input will be a list of positive numbers, decimal or integers, and the output will be a pie-chart where each of the input values are represented by separate colors, and a percentage value outside each of the areas.

**Rules:**

- The colors must be visually distinguishable (the exact colors are optional)
- There will be at least two, and maximum 10 input values
- The radius of the circle must be in the range `[100 300]` pixels

  - Vector graphics are OK as long as the default output gives a radius of `[100, 300]` pixels
- The percentage values shall be integers

  - There is no strict rule saying where the percentage value shall be placed, but it must be easily seen which area it belongs to
  - The distance between the closest character and the outer edge of the circle must be in the range `[5, 40]` pixels
  - The font is optional
- The plot may or may not have black lines separating each region
- Functions made for creating pie charts, for instance, MATLAB: `pie`, Python: `matplotlib.pyplot.pie` and Mathematica: `PieChart` are not allowed
- Normal rounding rules (up if it's `(1.00, 0.5]`, down if it's `(0.5, 0.00)`)
- If the percentage value of a slice is smaller than `0.5%`, output `0%`. The slice must still be included in the plot.
- Please provide plots for examination (or a link to an interpreter). It's enough to show only the plot with 10 input values (to avoid very long answers)

**Examples**

Please use the example values below. You can convert the lists to an appropriate format using a [numeric list converter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/66345/make-a-numeric-list-converter), for instance this [27 byte one](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=l%29l_5ms%60-SerS%25*%5CS-_o_'%28%23%28f-&input=%20%3B%0A%7B16%2C2%2C77%2C29%7D) by [jimmy23013](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/25180/jimmy23013).

```
x = [0.3, 1.2]
```

[image]

```
x = [3, 6, 2, 10]
```

[image]

```
x = [0.4387, 0.3816, 0.7655, 0.7952, 0.1869, 0.4898, 0.4456, 0.6463, 0.7094, 0.7547]
```

[image]

Comment: "The radius of the circle must be in the range [100 300] pixels." Are vector graphics allowed too?

Comment: @MartinBüttner, yes. That's OK, as long as the output from the program looks like it's between [100, 300] by default. Is that a sufficient answer?

Comment: R rounds 0.5 to 0. Is that a problem?

Comment: It's ok to round `0.5` to zero if that's default. But `0.50001` must be rounded to 1.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Mathematica, <s>186</s> <s>183</s> 164 bytes

```
Graphics[{Hue@#,Disk[{0,0},{1,1},a=2Pi{##}],Black,Text[ToString@Round[100(#2-#)]<>"%",5Through@{Cos,Sin}@Mean@a/4]}&@@@Partition[Accumulate[#/Tr@#]~Prepend~0,2,1]]&
```

Could be golfed further. Currently generates a `Graphics` object. Test cases:

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>311</s> <s>310</s> <s>302</s> 298 bytes

```js
a=>{with(Math)document.write(`<svg height=300>`+a.map(n=>`<path fill=#${(p*4e3|0).toString(16)} d=M135,150L${c(o=100,v=0)}A${[o,o,0,(v=n/=s)+.5|0,0,c(o)]}Z /><text x=${(z=c(135,v/=2))[0]} y=${z[p+=n,1]}>${n*o+.5|0}%</text>`,c=r=>[sin(d=PI*2*(v+p))*r+135,cos(d)*r+150],p=s=0,a.map(n=>s+=n)).join``)}
```

*Saved a byte with help from @Neil!*

### Explanation

Writes some SVG to the HTML of the current page. Builds the chart with centre point `135 x 150` of radius `100px` and text at a radius of `135px` from the centre.

```js
var solution =

a=>{
  with(Math)
  document.write(       // write to HTML body
    `<svg height=300>`+ // create 300px x 300px SVG canvas (width defaults to 300px)
    a.map(n=>           // for each number
      
      // Get the hex colour by multiplying the current position by (roughly) 0xfff
      `<path fill=#${(p*4e3|0).toString(16)
      
      // Calculate the path of the pie slice
      } d=M135,150L${c(o=100,v=0)}A${[o,o,0,(v=n/=s)+.5|0,0,c(o)]
      
      // Text
      }Z /><text x=${(z=c(135,v/=2))[0]} y=${z[p+=n,1]}>${n*o+.5|0}%</text>`,
      
      // Returns [ x, y ] for a certain radius at position v around the pie
      c=r=>[sin(d=PI*2*(v+p))*r+135,cos(d)*r+150],
      p=s=0,             // p = current position around pie (0 - 1)
      a.map(n=>s+=n)     // s = sum of all numbers
    ).join``
    
    +`</svg>` // <- this is just here for the test, so multiple charts can be displayed
  )
}

// Test
;[
  [0.3, 1.2],
  [3, 6, 2, 10],
  [0.4387, 0.3816, 0.7655, 0.7952, 0.1869, 0.4898, 0.4456, 0.6463, 0.7094, 0.7547]
].map(c=>solution(c));
```

Comment: I think you can save a few bytes using `with(Math)c=r=>[sin(d=PI*2*(v+p))*r+135,cos(d)*r+150]`.

Comment: Hmm, you might have to write `with(Math)var solution = a=>` etc.

Comment: Hmm, actually I can use `with`. I think I might have been in strict mode when I tried it last...

Comment: @Neil Got it in there, thanks. I'm pretty sure there's a fair bit more golfing that can be done on this, since I was rushing a bit when I wrote it.

Comment: Only saved 1 byte? I guess it's a start...

Answer (score 6):

## Python + PIL, <s>365</s> 355

```
from math import*;from random import*
from PIL import Image,ImageDraw
L,a,r=256,0,0.8;l,p,c=L/2,L/6,(L,L,L);I=Image.new('RGB',(L,L),c);D=ImageDraw.Draw(I)
x=input()
for i in x:b=a+ceil(360.0*i/sum(x));D.pieslice((p,p,L-p,L-p),int(a),int(b),tuple(map(randrange,c)));t=(a+b)*0.00872;D.text((l+cos(t)*l*r,l+sin(t)*l*r),str(int((b-a)/3.6))+'%',0);a=b
I.show()
```

[image]

Result for the largest example list :

[image]

Comment: In Python 2, isn't `eval(raw_input())` equivalent to Python 2's `input()`?

Comment: @cat yes it is !